# Key longer than 255 chars in a UTF8 mysql database

Tags: mysql, django, utf-8, django-south

I need to store URLs longer than 255 characters in an existing Django/South/MySQL application. These URLs are used as foreign keys. The issue is that the collation is UTF8, so if I increase the max_length of the URLField to, say, 512, I am getting the following error:

```
'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes'
```

I guess the reason is that in UTF8, each character can potentially be 3 bytes long, so with even just 256 characters, I could get over the limit.

As the URL should only include ASCII characters, I tried to change the collation of the specific table to ASCII in a (data) migration, and it seemed to work well: after migrating, I can successfully change max_length to 512 in a subsequent schema migration and store longer URLs.

However when bootstrapping the database, I am having the issue that it tries to set up the database without going through migrations:

```
syncdb --all
migrate --fake
```

syncdb, of course fails because it again tries to create the foreign key which is too long (migration to adjust collation of the database is not run).

If I syncdb without --all, (to then run migrations without --fake), it fails saying that some of the authentication tables do not exist.

Any idea of the proper way to increase that max_length limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best, and possibly only solution: Don't use urls as foreign keys at all.

Put the urls in a table with a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) (auto increment integer, for instance). Use that key for foreign keys and just put a unique index on the url column to prevent duplicate urls.

Comment: This is definitely a much better design. If you consider the total calculations required to do the join, consider the amount of bits required to store a string of 768 characters versus an integer; then think of what the computer has to do to match equality between the two: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

A less invasive and less clean approach I took was to:

- Use [indexes with prefix size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html). this can only be done using a raw SQL statement, in a migration.
- Since migrations are usually not run when setting up a new database, I made a management command which creates the indexes, this command must be run after syncdb and migrate:

  ```
  ./manage.py syncdb --all
  ./manage.py migrate --fake
  ./manage.py create_indexes
  ```

With `myapp/management/commands/create_indexes.py` being a management command that runs the raw SQL commands to create indexes with prefix.